# Showing HTML file in Node js Application

Tags: html, node.js

I am new on Node.js and I have app.js file like:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World'));
app.listen(port);
console.log(`App running on http://localhost:${port}`);
```

I also have index.html file in the same folder with app.js. Here there is a HTML5 website.
When I run the project I can see Hello World text in browser, How can I show this HTML file from my app.js so when I deploy it, it should show me responsive HTML file instead of Hello World?

I tried

```
app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html');
  });
```

But didn't see a difference.

Comment: "But didn't see a difference." — Did you restart the server after you changed its source code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To make your code example work you'll need to specify an absolute path, try using this:

```js
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
```

---

Another way would be to use EJS (https://ejs.co/)

In your example, you could do the following:

**Install EJS:**

`npm install ejs`

**Set the View Engine to EJS:**

`app.set('view engine', 'ejs')`

**- Move your index.html file to a folder called "views" and also rename the file to index.ejs**
`views/index.ejs`

**In your app.get() handler, use:**

`res.render('index')`

**Final Result:**

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

const port = 8080;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

(note: I also moved your console.log to inside app.listen)

Answer (score -1):

I found this on another stack overflow question, it should work

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/views/test.html', 'utf8', function(err, text){
    res.send(text);
});
```